# Cooja simulation of Mist application

Tags: contiki

Has anyone successfully done a Cooja simulation with a Thingsquare Mist application?

I try to compile the hello-world or the mesh-node examples for the various Mote types but most of them failed on missing ip64-conf.h (naturally, since the target is not supported on Mist) but those that has some sort of Mist port (exp2420 for example) failed because the application can't fit in ROM.

I tried manipulating the line on the `Compile commands` tab to make it build for any other platform but even though the build is ok the `Create` button never gets enabled.

I'm using the Instant Contiki 2.6 environment and building code from Thingsquare Mist 1.0.1

Answer (score 0):

Though Thingsquare mist code is based on Contiki 2.6 you can't compile thingsquare code inside instant Contiki (cooja) as it is. The current configuration for make file in mist only supports cc1101, cc2420, cc2538 and two or three platform. Please have a look at thingsquare website for details. Things to do.

1. You need to change the simulation settings for the specific platform. Do n't waste your time in cooja for running mist apps; it 'll not compile. Have a look to this link: https://github.com/contiki-os/contiki/wiki/An-Introduction-to-Cooja#wiki-Create_a_Hello_World_simulation
2. For minimizing the missing ip64-conf.h. Just create a  ip64-conf.h file inside mesh-node folder and paste the following code.

`#ifndef IP64_CONF_H`

`#define IP64_CONF_H`

`#include "ip64-slip-interface.h"`

`#include "ip64-null-driver.h"`

`#define IP64_CONF_UIP_FALLBACK_INTERFACE_SLIP 1`

`#define IP64_CONF_UIP_FALLBACK_INTERFACE ip64_slip_interface`

`#define IP64_CONF_INPUT                  ip64_slip_interface_input`

`#define IP64_CONF_ETH_DRIVER             ip64_null_driver`

`#endif /* IP64_CONF_H */`

3.To minimize ROM Overflow error; you need to install msp430-gcc compile 4.7.0. Have a look to this link: http://wiki.contiki-os.org/doku.php?id=msp430x

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That's a bit surprising since Thingsquare promotes both Cooja and Instant Contiki in their marketing material... I guess it's not done yet so I'll just wait, or see if I can make my own ip64-conf.h work. (Running the Contiki Hello World simulation doesn't really help me since I'm developing a Mist application)